# Authentication system

Tags: symfony

I do have the following security.yml:

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    Frontend\AccountBundle\Entity\User:
     id: sha256salted_encoder

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [in_memory, user_db]
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                foo: { password: test, roles: ROLE_USER }
    user_db:
        entity: { class: Frontend\AccountBundle\Entity\User, property: email }

access_control:
     - { path: ^/secarea/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

If I am going to login as the user....

...foo:

- on EVERY PAGE foo is logged in as: foo  // green background
- on EVERY PAGE foo is authenticated

...as db user:

- only on pages which I declared in access_control the db_user is logged in and authenticated // green background
- on other pages the user is logged in //yellow background, but not authenticated

Why is there a different?

Comment: Do I have to give a user from db a role? Can I set a default role to db user?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use an firewall?

i stumpled upon this problem some time ago and ended up here:

[app.user is not accessible from unsecured area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702601/app-user-is-not-accessible-from-unsecured-area)